# mypy arg should be one of a set of functions

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

```
from enum import Enum

def strategy_a(x: float, y: float) -> float:
    return x + y

def strategy_b(x: float, y: float) -> float:
    return x * y

class Strategy(Enum):
    A = strategy_a
    B = strategy_b

def run_strategy(x: float, y: float, strategy: Strategy) -> float:
    return strategy(x, y)
```

Let's say I have something like this where `run_strategy`'s args `strategy` takes in some possible set of functions. How can I type it such that only those functions can be passed without mypy throwing an error.

Note: the above code throws an error as mypy complains Strategy is not a callable.

The above code is then run as

```
run_strategy(5, 17, Strategy.A)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A walk-around would be to specify a protocol `Strategy` that prescribes an implementation of **call**, and rebrand the `Enum` item as inheriting that protocol, see example `blah.py`:

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import Protocol


def strategy_a(x: float, y: float) -> float:
    return x + y


def strategy_b(x: float, y: float) -> float:
    return x * y


class Strategy(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, x: float, y: float) -> float:
        ...


class StrategyChoice(Enum, Strategy):
    A = strategy_a
    B = strategy_b


def run_strategy(x: float, y: float, strategy: StrategyChoice) -> float:
    return strategy(x, y)
```

```
mypy ./blah.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: Thanks but in this case does the Protocol enforce anything? or would it not simply be the same do add an arbitrary __call__ to StrategyChoice

Comment: Enforcing is a strong word for an untyped language :) You could in principle add an unimplemented `call` to `StrategyChoice`, but I find it slightly weird for an `Enum` to contain deferred functions. Adding it to the `Protocol` and inheriting it instead is more natural: you are claiming that a Strategy is anything you can call with 2 floats to get a float, and a `StrategyChoice` is an `Enum` (ie. a choice) that also acts as a `Strategy`.